# Strange behavior by list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries as follows:

```
a = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'d':4, 'e':5, 'f':6}]
```

Now I want another list `b` to have same contents as a but with one `(key,value)` pair extra. So I do it as:

```
b = a.copy()
for item in b:
  item['x'] = 6
```

But now both the lists `a` and `b` have `'x': 6` sitting in them.

```
>>> b
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'x': 6}, {'d': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'x': 6}]
>>> a
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'x': 6}, {'d': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'x': 6}]
```

I also tried this:

```
c = a[:]
for item in c:
  item['q'] = 12
```

And now all the three lists have `'q': 12`.

```
>>> c
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'x': 6, 'q': 12}, {'d': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'x': 6, 'q': 12}]
>>> b
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'x': 6, 'q': 12}, {'d': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'x': 6, 'q': 12}]
>>> a
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'x': 6, 'q': 12}, {'d': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'x': 6, 'q': 12}]
```

I can't understand how is this working. This would have been acceptable if I had done `b = a`. But why for `b = a.copy()` and `c = a[:]`.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: - A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the
  extent possible) inserts *the same objects* into it that the
  original contains.

Comment: - A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively,
  inserts *copies* into it of the objects found in the original.

Comment: ^^ from the documentation.  You can access this quickly via `help(copy)` in a python shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy a dictionary and copy all referenced objects use the `deepcopy()` function from the `copy` module instead of dict's method `copy()`.

```
import copy
a = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'d':4, 'e':5, 'f':6}]
b = copy.deepcopy(d)
```

Comment: Thanks. This surely works but I want to know why the method I'm doing is not working:)

Comment: I edited it, but since it's not approved yet, copying a dictionary copies the dictionary's references. The objects it's referencing are the same objects, you need to do a deepcopy to copy the referenced objects as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @maziyank's solution. The explanation is that except `copy.deepcopy()` all the methods are just pointing one variable to the previous variable.
Thus any change to any of them will transcend to all the variables that point to the same variable.